# Guess what I am, I am not a Saint!

Tags: riddle, word

- I have amazing powers of seduction
- Thieves and boxers love me
- They made a Hollywood film about me
- My music is catchy as hell
- I help in enriching your diet

Comment: are you DOCTOR STRANGE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have amazing powers of seduction:

> Seductive things really **hook** you

Thieves and boxers love me

> A **hook** can be used to steal things stealthily, or floor an opposing pugilist

They made a Hollywood film about me

> Shiver me timbers, [they certainly did!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102057/)

My music is catchy as hell

> Pop songs rely on great **hooks**

I help in enriching your diet

> Fish is a great healthy food, and can be caught with a **hook**

Comment: Perfect answer!